# How to make a malloced 2D array show nothing when printed out?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am working on a Tic Tac Toe Game and have a malloced 2D array of characters for the Grid **3x3**.

I Test printed the values in the array and got `0`. I am planning on making a grid around the array output but for that to work the output has to be empty not `0`. Please Help I want the output to be nothing.

```
/*Malloced Array*/

array = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * row);

for(ii = 0; ii < row; ii++)
{
    arraySec = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * col);
    array[ii] = arraySec;
}

/*Test Print*/
for(ii = 0; ii < row; ii++)
{
    for(jj = 0; jj < col; jj++)
    {
        printf("\n%d:%d = %d", ii, jj, array[ii][jj]);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
0:0 = 0

0:1 = 0

0:2 = 0

1:0 = 0

1:1 = 0

1:2 = 0

2:0 = 0

2:1 = 0

2:2 = 0
```

Comment: When you say you want the output to be 'nothing' what do you actually mean? Do you want a blank (space) character output?

Comment: yeah something like that it can be null, blank space. Just when printing out it has to not show up on the screen. But if I put the char of say X or O in the array I want that character to show up instead.

Comment: malloc defaults to '0' for some reason. Can I put an empty string ' ' as each array element or is there a better way than hard coding that in?

Comment: Exactly - see answer!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if you want to print a 'space' character (i.e. nothing shows) for any grid position that's not yet 'used' (i.e. has a `O` or `X` in it), then you need to add/change two things in your code.

First, you need to initialise your array to blank characters:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < row; ii++) {
    for(jj = 0; jj < col; jj++) {
        array[ii][jj] = ' '; // Set to the blank (space) character
    }
}
```

Then, in your "test print" you need to output the characters ***as characters*** - not as numbers (integers):

```
for(ii = 0; ii < row; ii++) {
    for(jj = 0; jj < col; jj++) {
        printf("\n%d:%d = %c", ii, jj, array[ii][jj]); // %c will print the character as such, but you won't see it!
    }
}
```